# Fetching data using last Datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have to show these details in a gridview as Tempname as unique and associated datetime in drodown and the last run by name in a label. Unable to upload the Table picture as i dont have enough reputation.

```
    private void GridLoading()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = Common.LoadingGrid();
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            Label lblName = e.Row.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
            ds = Common.RunByDate(lblName.Text);
            DropDownList ddl = e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;

            ddl.DataTextField = "RunDate";
            ddl.DataValueField = "RunDate";
            ddl.DataSource = ds;
            ddl.DataBind();
            var items = ddl.Items;
          }           
    }
```

But i am unable to get the Runby name in the label.How can i display it?Below are my stored procedures

```
    Select distinct TempName from SV_JobHistoryTable 

    SELECT TempName,RunDate
    FROM SV_JobHistoryTable  where TempName=@tempname
```

Comment: Runby name column is in which table?

Comment: This is the table name SV_JobHistoryTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far what i have understood is, you want to get the `Unique TempName` with the `Lastest RunDate`, all you need is this query:

```
SELECT RunByName, MAX(RunDate)
FROM SV_JobHistoryTable  
WHERE TempName = @tempname 
GROUP BY RunByName
```

Comment: Not MAX(RunDate) i am getting everything except the Runby name in the gridview

Comment: What is RunBy Name, is it a separate column name of the table SV_JobHistoryTable?

Comment: Yes it is a column in the table

Comment: Though i am still confused what is the difference between TempName and RunByName but See my edited answer. Hope this helps to get RunBy Name as per latest RunDate.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT TempName,RunDate,max(Runbyname)
    FROM SV_JobHistoryTable  where TempName=@tempname 
    group by TempName,RunDate
```

Comment: If i do like this i wont get the distinct TempName.Anyway i am getting the ditinct TempName my problem is with getting the last RunBy name and binding it to the grid

Comment: Every rundate is associated with the name

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
    SELECT TOP 1
         RunByName, RunDate
    FROM 
        SV_JobHistoryTable 
    WHERE 
        TempName = @tempname                    
    ORDER BY 
        RunDate DESC
```

Or do you want to record more entries than one?